# Why show/hide table it's so computationally expensive?

Tags: javascript, performance, css-tables

I'm working with quite big table and because I'm doing some formatting in Javascript after the table has been downloaded, I want to hide the table (`display:none`) until it's ready (than I change to ("display","")). It's working right, the only problem it's super slow in IE8, but if I don't hide the table it's super fast, why? Is there a way to avoid this?
(My problem is that I'm showing a ugly table to the user and than I change it in front of his face, I don't like this)

Comment: try to use pagination (split your table across multiple pages) or try to assign via css `table-layout: fixed` to your table (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/table-layout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `style.visibility` to hidden/visible instead of setting display. This will allow the table to maintain its position, which removes the need for a page redraw.